# Python не компилируется в vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]"cmd" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Что значит: 'Python не `помпилируеться` в vs code' ? Где вы пишите `"cmd" ` ? Текст кода надо приводить `текстом`, а не картинкой.

Comment: У меня не компилиться даже пустой проект( Код не причем)

Comment: Для начала самое простое. Без VSC в консоли у Вас скрипт работает? если да то проблема в VSC, если нет то дело в компе и наверное самое простое переустановить питон если дело в нем.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что текст долженбыть текстом, а не картинкой

Answer (score 2):

VSC - это просто "клей", который вызывает установленныек системе комманд-лайн утилиты.

У Вас неправильные настройки VSC в файле launch.json в директории .vscode

Если посмотреть на картинку, в её правую нижнюю часть, то над текстом ошибки приведена команда, которая вызвала эту ошибку.

Надо посмотреть, откуда эта команда берется, и сделать так, чтобы ошибки не было.

Попробуйте сделать настройки в соответствии с рководством:

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/learn/modules/python-install-vscode/

Ну, или вот на ютьюбе:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Re2KdeoRhXY

Comment: Тут дело не точно в коде, у меня не запускаеться файли .py

Comment: А какаяу Вас операционная система? А как вы устанавливалив неё питон? Какая версия питона? В общем, вы попробуйте сделать установку питона по какому то руководству, скорее всего, должно получиться

Comment: А, я кажется, понял. У Вас VS Code, вы заходите в питоновский файл, нажимаете F5 и получаете ту ошибку, котрая в вопросе? так?

Comment: Да, у меня установлено дополнение Python

Comment: VSC - это просто "клей", который вызывает установленныек системе комманд-лайн утилиты. У Вас неправильные настройки VSC в файле launch.json в директории .vscode - и теперь у Вас достаточно инфы, чтобынагуглить правильные настройки

Comment: Не уверен так как, эта проблема возникла после попытки установмть Anaconda для Python и я изменял в переменных средах Path и после этого не работает

Comment: Анаконда соответствует своему названию... в общем, анаконда - это такой пакет для людей, которые не хотят заморачиваться с настройками, а хотят заходить в свои "блокноты" и не выходить оттуда. Это особый мир "дата-сатанистов". Анаконда поставила Вам в систему вторую версию питона и что то сделала с путтями, прописанными в path. Советую удалить её и следы её жизнедеятельности и попробовать заново

Comment: Сделал уже, но проблема осталась

Comment: Надо найти, в каком месте в команду вписывается лишнее слово "cmd". Посмотрите файл launch.json, документацию, попробуйте выполнить запуск скрипта питоновского из командной строки, проверьте path. Какой то из этих советов может помочь. Больше, к сожалению, ничего подсказать не смогу, наверное. Хотя, можете добавить свой launch.json к вопросу?